# Can Mutt be used to access Inbox messages in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting, email, mutt

I've got scripts that collect data on errors and sends them into a ticketing system. If any developments occur regarding an existing ticket, I want to be able to access the email inbox to get the ticket number so that I can include this in the reply. This will result in the ticketing system including the new information in the old ticket instead of creating a new ticket every time. Is this possible?

I've been looking online for how I might be able to do this but I haven't yet found anything that looks like bash commands to access the inbox programmatically and save a message's information to a variable.

Comment: Can you describe the workflow in more detail? Is your Inbox on your local system? What mailer daemon do you use? Maybe you can use the `.forward` file to process incoming mails by piping the messages into a command instead of accessing the Inbox from a script.

Comment: Yes, mutt can be used to access inbox messages. (But it may or may not be the best tool for the task.) If you want an answer that's actually useful, you need to ask a more precise question. What do you want to do? I guess search for an email, where and based on what criteria?